# Prevent WooCommerce images from getting cut off

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm in the middle of building a WordPress site.

Many images are getting cut off, as the pictures are filling up the height before the width. I want to change it to be the other way around - the width is more important.

http://www.new.brooklynpartyrental.com/product/rectangle-tables/

What kind of custom css should I add to make this possible?

Thank you!!

Comment: so you want the image to fit the container?

Comment: Yes - (the original image is NOT cut off. )

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CSS or an HTML issue. The **image source file itself** is cut off and is given an inline height and width greater than the parent div for which it is filling. Neither a height nor width should be specified in the image element, and it can simply be given the CSS rule of width: 100%.

Answer (score -1):

Disable all Hard Crop options in **WooCommerce** > **Settings** > **Products** > **Display**. Your new upload product images wouldn't cut off anymore.

Now you can install [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin, activate it and go to Tools > Regen. Thumbnails. Click *Regenerate all thumbnails* and wait for the magic.